# telnet a multiples servidores con manejo de exepciones en python

Tags: python, telnet

estoy queriendo ejecutar comandos con varios servidores a través de un telnet en python. El problema que no estoy pudiendo resolver es si me falla el telnet con un servidor, como hacer para que continue en el resto, ya que la excepcion me saca del sistema. Si no falla el tlenet, adnda todo bien, pero quiero poder manejar esa expeción en forma más eficiente.
Gracias por cualquier aporte!
Asi sería el código que tengo:

```
import telnetlib
import sys
sitios = {'a': '172.10.10.1','b': ''172.10.10.2','c': ''172.10.10.3'}
timeout = 10
def conexion():
    summary = ''
    for sitio,ip in sitios.items():
        tn = telnetlib.Telnet(ip, 6000, timeout)    
        try:
            tn.read_until(b"\r\n", 5)
            tn.write('LGI')
            summary += sitio + ': Conexion OK\n'
        except:
            summary += sitio + ': Sin Conexion \n'
    return  summary
print(conexion())`
```

Comment: Hombre, claro que te saca. Tienes puesto un `sys.exit()` ¿qué es lo que querrías que ocurriera si el sitio falla? Podrías simplemente cambiar ese `sys.exit()` por un `print(f"La conexión con {sitio} ha fallado")`, e incluso añadir algún mensaje especial al `summary`. Así se "saltaría" el sitio con problemas e iría al siguiente

Comment: Hola, en lugar de sys.exit(), ren realidad tengo: summary += sitio + ': Sin Conexion \n', para indicar los sitios sin conexión, pero esto no hace que me devuelva los situis conectados y no conectados. Me da error: socket.timeout: timed out

Comment: Entonces deberías corregir el código del post..